# Deploy a SSR Nuxt 2 application on firebase

Tags: firebase, nuxt.js

I have some troubles deploying a Nuxt 2.4 application on Firebase.
I tried these 2 tutorials but they seem outdated:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYUWsjUxxUQ
- https://github.com/davidroyer/nuxt2-ssr-firebase

With the first tutorial, I could make my app working on local (after few hours and with a lot of modifications for babel integration) but I never could serve or deploy it. I thought the tutorial was old and manipulations can't be exactly done like the guy did.

With the second tutorial, I cloned the repository to try to deploy the example. I had to change 2 things : install Node 8 instead of Node 10 and upgrading firebase-admin to the last version in prod/server dir. Here is what I got:

- `npm run setup` is ok

---

- `npm run dev` is ok and the project works fine

---

- `npm run build` is ok

---

- `npm run serve` fails.

First I got this error :

```
The Cloud Functions emulator requires the module "firebase-admin" to be version >7.0.0 so your version is too old. You can probably fix this by running "npm install firebase-admin@latest" in your functions directory.
```

Indeed, the version configured in package.json is the 5.13. I did the update from the `prod/server` dir, and I get the 8.0.0. 
And then I got a different error about gRPC :

```
Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
Expected directory: node-v57-darwin-x64-unknown
Found: [node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown]
This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system
```

I tried `npm rebuild` as mentionned, without success.

---

- `npm run deploy` fails.

I get this trace:

```
i  deploying functions, hosting
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing prod/server directory for uploading...
Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'acorn'
Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before deploying.
```

Of course, I tried the npm install from prod/server dir, but nothing changed.
Is there somewhere i can find a tutorial that can help me deploy my SSR app to firebase ? Thanks in avdance !

EDIT 1 : 
After a few modifications on my package.json

- upgrading firebase-functions and express to the latest versions
- downgrading firebase-admin to the 7.0.0 version
- adding acorn

I can serve and deploy but I get a "504 gateway time-out" webpage when I call the URL....

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? As you said there is nothing available online to achieve this

Comment: No, I gave up and I deployed my app on Heroku. So much easier

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run `npm install grpc` inside **functions** folder?